# how to update a sql varchar column using JAVA handle createStatement INNO DB

Tags: java, mysql

I need to update my columns using JAVA Handle and create statement, but from what I have researched I need to be using batch if its all (or most) of the columns I desired to update?

This is the code i've written thus far:

```
private int deletePlayer(Handle handle, String username, String table) {
    logger.debug("Deleting from table " + table);
    String sqlCommand;

     sqlCommand = String.format("UPDATE %s SET rank = 1 "
            + "SET level = 1 "
            + "SET exp = 0 "
            + "SET prof = '' "
            + "SET guild = '' "
            + "SET varname = '' "
            + "WHERE name = :username", table);

    handle.createStatement(sqlCommand)
            .bind("username", username)
            .execute();        
    return 1;
}
```

I broke it up to try and pinpoint the problem and found that the MySQL Command:

```
sqlCommand = String.format("UPDATE %s SET varname = '' WHERE name = :username", table);
```

And the like is not working. This is more than likely because of the string/char concatenation.

Also, should I be using batch instead?

Stack Trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15b2043

Please, if you are going to make this post down please tell me why and I will be more than happy to fix it to your liking, or clarify, so that it adheres to the forum conduct/terms of service/ et cetera.

Comment: You should be using a single update statement to update all the columns. That's just ridiculous what you're doing. And use a `PreparedStatement`, not a regular `Statement`.

Comment: It won't fix the string problem.

Comment: But it'll fix a horrible code smell. Besides, you're not saying anything about what's happening. Do you get an eexception? A stacktrace? "Is not working" is not very helpful.

Comment: Yes I get a stacktrace. To regurgitate, I broke it up and pinpointed that the problem is coming from updating the VARCHARs not the INTEGERs

Comment: Stack Trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15b2043

Comment: Use PreparedStatement instead of String.format. The values your are trying to format into your String value still need to enclosed in single quotes, '%s', but this leaves you open to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the comma between keyword set to update DB values.

```
sqlCommand = String.format("UPDATE %s SET rank = 1 "
        + "SET level = 1, "
        + "SET exp = 0, "
        + "SET prof = '', "
        + "SET guild = '', "
        + "SET varname = '' "
        + "WHERE name = :username", table);
```